# Why can't I use Remote Site names that have been previously used?

Tags: remote-site

I created a new Remote Site so I could make callouts to an API. I deleted it for testing, and when I tried to add it again, it said,

"This Remote Site Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name."

Does this mean you can never create a remote site with the same name as one that has long been deleted? Is there some kind of waiting period before I can use that name again, or is it gone forever? I would really like to use the original name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many "managed" components in a "managed package" become a permanent part of the package's metadata once uploaded in a release version. You can delete the item later, but you can never reuse its name. You will need to use a different name, or recover it from the Deleted Items section of your package (the docs say this should work, but I've never used it successfully).

Comment: I have never uploaded a release version though, only beta. I checked the Deleted Components section just in case, and it's empty.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, that's probably correct. I don't think it's possible to reclaim a used Remote Site name at all if it's ever been uploaded. I've never had to try, I only know what's in the docs.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I wish it would have warned me before I deleted it that I would never be able to use that name again.